# Get value from function in loop nodejs

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I'm a newbie in javascript and node js. I actually want to compare two data based on MySQL value.

what I want to do is Loop for the pair of `data -> get` value from `db -> concat` pair of data and `value -> endloop`

Here's my code

**routes/masterdata.js**

```
var Masterdata = require('../models/Masterdata');
var outputFile = {}
for (var i = 0; i < dataFile.length; i++) {
  if (dataFile[i]['existing'] != null) {
    for (var x = 0; x < dataFile.length; x++) {
      var param = {
        tech_row: dataFile[i]['existing'],
        tech_col: dataFile[x]['new']
      };

      Masterdata.compareData(param, function(err, rows) {
        console.log(rows);
        outputFile.push({
          value: rows
        });
      });
    }
  }
}

console.log(outputFile);
```

**models/Masterdata.js**

```
var Masterdata = {
  compareData: function(param, callback) {
    return db.query('SELECT value FROM sod_matrix WHERE TECH_NAME_ROW = ? AND TECH_NAME_COL = ?', [param.tech_row, param.tech_col], callback);

  }
}
```

My Question is how to populate data from function compare data into an array in the loop?

Comment: outputFile is an Object, not an Array, that's why you can't push your info into it. Use var outputFile = []; instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var completed=[];
var Masterdata = require('../models/Masterdata');
var outputFile = []; //should be an array
for (var i = 0; i < dataFile.length; i++) {
  if (dataFile[i]['existing'] != null) {
    for (var x = 0; x < dataFile.length; x++) {
      var param = {
        tech_row: dataFile[i]['existing'],
        tech_col: dataFile[x]['new']
      };
      completed.push(new Promise(resolve, reject){
        Masterdata.compareData(param, function(err, rows) {
          if(err)
          {
            reject(err);
          }
          else
          {
            console.log(rows);
            outputFile.push(rows); //that;s pretty enough
            resolve();
          }
        });
      });
    }
  }
}
Promise.all(completed)
 .then((res)
 {
   console.log(outputFile);
 });
```

Comment: i've try this but outputFile return Undefined how to make it synchronous? thank you

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't notice that `Masterdata.compareData` was async. This way, you should use promises or callbacks. I edited my sample to show how this can be archieved using promises.